# How to make Item slots in custom v-data-table component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I am working on a wrapper to create customizable component based on vuetify data-table.

I would need it to have similar functionality when it comes to slots. How can I achieve behavior like this?

```
<MyCustomDataTable>
  :items="items"
  :headers="headers"
>

    <template #item.status="{ item }">
      <v-icon v-if="item.status === 0"> ok </v-icon>
      <v-icon v-else> error </v-icon>
    </template>

</MyCustomDataTable>
```

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: found no answer to my question there :(

Comment: You must provide what you tried with component `MyCustomDataTable`